# Failing to load kernel module

Tags: kernel, freebsd, kernel-modules

So, I have just started going through [Designing BSD Rootkits](https://nostarch.com/rootkits.htm) and I seem to have ran into a problem right away.

**hello.c**:

```
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/module.h>
#include <sys/kernel.h>
#include <sys/systm.h>

static int
load(struct module *module, int cmd, void *arg) {
    int error = 0;

    switch (cmd) {
    case MOD_LOAD:
        uprintf("hello, world!\n");
        break;
    case MOD_UNLOAD:
        uprintf("good-bye");
        break;
    default:
        error = EOPNOTSUPP;
        break;
    }

    return(error);
}

static moduledata_t hello_mod = {
    "hello", 
    load,
    NULL
};

DECLARE_MODULE(hello, hello_mod, SI_SUB_DRIVERS, SI_ORDER_MIDDLE);
```

Compiling with the following Makefile appears to work perfectly fine:

**Makefile**:

```
KMOD=   hello
SRCS=   hello.c

.include <bsd.kmod.mk>
```

But when running **`sudo kldload ./hello.ko`** it tells me the module is already:

```
kldload: can't load ./hello.ko: module already loaded or in kernel
```

Running **`sudo kldstat -v | grep hello`** doesn't find anything.

As a final step, I attempted to unload the module using **`sudo kldunload hello`** and I get the following output:

```
kldunload: can't find file hello.ko
```

I have tried running the above commands both as `root` and `freebsd` with no success.

Just for completeness, here is more information

**ls -la**:

```
total 224 drwxr-xr-x  2 freebsd  freebsd     512 Dec  7 22:40 . drwxr-xr-x  4 freebsd  freebsd     512 Dec  7 22:16 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 freebsd  freebsd    1386 Dec  7 22:40 .depend.hello.o
-rw-r--r--  1 freebsd  freebsd      50 Dec  7 22:07 Makefile
-rw-r--r--  1 freebsd  freebsd       0 Dec  7 22:40 export_syms
-rw-r--r--  1 freebsd  freebsd     488 Dec  7 22:08 hello.c
-rw-r--r--  1 freebsd  freebsd    3176 Dec  7 22:40 hello.kld
-rwxr-xr-x  1 freebsd  freebsd  199904 Dec  7 22:40 hello.ko
-rw-r--r--  1 freebsd  freebsd    2864 Dec  7 22:40 hello.o lrwxr-xr-x  1 freebsd  freebsd      26 Dec  7 22:40 machine -> /usr/src/sys/arm64/include
```

**uname -mrs**:

```
FreeBSD 12.0-RELEASE arm64
```

**platform**

```
raspberry Pi 3B
```

I did find a similar question on the [FreeBSD forums](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/cant-load-example-device-driver.64930/) from last year, but there was not resolution.

Any idea whats going on and how I can proceed?

Comment: cannot reproduce (12.0-RELEASE, but amd64). Does it also happen with other modules, eg. `kldload /boot/kernel/linux.ko`?

Comment: Yeah, I get the same problem if I try to load/unload the `zlib.ko` module. I don't appear to have the `linux.ko` module.

Comment: OK, so I can confirm I don't have issue if i run 12.0-RELEASE amd64. Maybe there is something missing in my install? But running on a different system gets me going. 
If i get the time to investigate running on the Pi, i will update this thread